# Using GCP DLP with DataFusion, unable to find template

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion, google-cloud-dlp

I have created a DLP Identification template named DLPTest in Project X.

My Datafusion resources are hosted in Project Y.

Issue is when I use the Redact plugin in Datafusion, and provide the template ID or path in the form - 
projects/X/locations/{LOCATION}/inspectTemplates/DLPTest or 
projects/X/inspectTemplates/DLPTest 

All permissions have been provided to datafusion SA, compute engine SA, DLP Service Account.  Datafusion fails to find the template, as it keeps searching for template in Project Y. 

> Error logs - 
> Caused by:com.google.api.gax.rpc.InvalidArgumentException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid path: 

Datafusion is expecting template in location projects/Y/inspectTemplates/projects/DLPTest

How do I enable DF to look for template in the correct location in separate project?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want Project Y (where your data fusion is in) to use resources from Project X (where the DLP is in) is to add the data fusion and compute engine service accounts of Project Y to Project X.

Notes:

- Data Fusion service account: service-xxxxxxx@gcp-sa-datafusion.iam.gserviceaccount.com
- Default compute engine service account: xxxxx-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com

**Project Y:**

1. Go to IAM & Admin -> IAM
2. Click View by: "Members"
3. Tick checkbox "Include Google-provided role grants"
4. Look for **service-(project number of Project Y)@gcp-sa-datafusion.iam.gserviceaccount.com** and **(project number of Project Y)-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com**
5. Add role "DLP Administrator" for **service-(project number of Project Y)@gcp-sa-datafusion.iam.gserviceaccount.com**

**Project X:**

1. Go to IAM & Admin -> IAM
2. Click **Add**
3. Under New Members, put **service-(project number of Project Y)@gcp-sa-datafusion.iam.gserviceaccount.com**
4. Grant role of "DLP Admininistrator"
5. Repeat step 2 to step 4 but this time put in **(project number of Project Y)-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com**

Now that you are able to set the permissions, Go back to Project Y and update your Redact to point to Project X.

1. Go to Data Fusion -> Studio
2. Click Redact-> Properties
3. Put the template ID you created in Project X, in my sample it is "test_template"
   [image]
4. Under Project ID, put the Project ID of Project X
   [image]
5. Run your Data Fusion pipeline

Comment: They didn't say they got a permission error, they got an error from data fusion. Datafusion is expecting template in location projects/Y/inspectTemplates/projects/DLPTest. This sounds like a bug, I'll check in with them on it.

Comment: @JordannaChord Yes it is not a permission error, I just posted the steps if ever they somewhat missed this. Also if "Project ID" is set to auto-detect it will be pointed to Project Y by default, changing the value to Project X should point to location projects/X/inspectTemplates/projects/DLPTest.

Comment: As mentioned by Ricco, it was more to do with the project permission and setup.  Steps provided solved the issue.  Additionally DLP needs enabled for project hosting datafusion, i.e. Project Y as well.  I did have issues with regional DLP template(though all resources in same region), but global DLP template worked fine.